# Automated creation of new App Registrations in AAD using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal

I just want to be sure that the following is not possible before I follow another path (Distributed Application or multi-tenant web-site).

I have a web-app plugin which needs to run some automated setup, like creating new App Registrations in the current tenant, which in turn requires access to the Microsoft Graph API, which requires an existing App Registration with Directory.ReadWrite.All etc.

I was hoping that I could have used a multi-tenant App Registration from my own tenant for this.

However, I can't seem to use Implicit grant flow as the redirect/reply URL's are unknown (the plugin is delivered to hundreds of customers, and each customer could have many environments).

The plugin can only use C# & JS, however, the C# part is 'isolated', so it can't display (web)forms.
Both ADAL and MSAL for .NET fails to open the login window as it is not running in UserInteractive mode.

I have used ADAL for JS, however, it does not seem to support native clients (non-web RedirectURI).

I have also tried to use MSAL for JS with https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient (Login succeeds, however the dialog hangs because JS loses access to it, cross-domain request) and urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob (displays “Open an app” after sign-in). I have disabled "protected mode" in IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth requires that you have a "known destination" to send the user too. Without this, it would be too easy to create a man-in-the-middle attack by hijacking the `redirect_uri` so that it points to a malicious site and capturing their token without the user knowing.

When using Authorization Code or Implicit grants in a multi-tenant scenario, *you* want to host the page that they're being redirected too. Your site captures the token they need and then redirects them back to their application.

The key to this workflow is encoding the final destination in the `state` parameter. Your server receives the token, decodes the final designation from the `state` parameter, and then redirects them to that location.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll setup a multi-tenant web-site.
I would simply have moved all the setup logic to that site. Didn’t think about doing an additional redirect.
Would it be safe enough/BP to redirect from my own hosted page to the customer using state?

Comment: That is generally how it is done, yes. It's the easiest way to handle it. Some folks add additional security by storing this data on their backend, keyed to a unique ID. They then send just that `id` in the state and use that to lookup a db record. This gives you an extra layer of protection by not shipping easily decoded data over the wire. In most cases this is overkill but if you have sensitive information in the route or a _lot_ of data, it is a reasonable path.